# send link to mail with POST parameters

Tags: php, html, email

I want to send mail to customer with HTML content and I want to send him link similar like this:

```
<a href="file.php?user_id=10"> some text </a>
```

I think, that it is bad way how to define this link with GET parameter user_id. Attribute user_id is sensitive information, so I want to be set like POST parameter. How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code/html (the form for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, with a tags. A tags are only for GETing, you need to use xmlhttprequests (not available in emails) or a form (which not all clients render properly)

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="10">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

That being said, user IDs typically are not sensitive information

Comment: User_id is not sensitive information in general. However, this file (file.php?user_id=10) perform sensitive action, which can be performed only by admin.

Comment: @Matej Surely you have authentication at some point, though? It wouldn't matter if someone gets hold of that link if you still require them to log in

Comment: @Matej And even if you did want to use POST to send the data, it's still very possible for someone to make a form on client side that does that with any ID they wish

Comment: Yes, so I only set the privilege for viewing this page only for admin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I think, that it is bad way how to define this link with GET parameter user_id.

It isn't.

> Attribute user_id is sensitive information

No, it isn't. Even when user IDs are at their most sensitive, people can still guess random ones.

> so I want to be set like POST parameter. How to do it?

You can't.

Links can't make POST requests.

Forms can, but many email clients don't support forms in HTML formatted email so it would be inadvisable to use them.

XMLHttpRequest can, but no email client lets you embed working JavaScript in an email.

If you did make a POST request, then the only people you would be hiding the information from would be people standing behind the user and staring at their address bar.

---

If you do need to add a layer of security then authenticate the user (e.g. with a username and password or OAuth) and/or accompany the data with a one-time authorisation token.